# Iterating List of Class Objects Issue in Drools Rule Engine

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

I learning Drools using Kie Workbench.
    my input will be name inside opportunityProduct class and i am expecting 
    the output in Ip inside Opportunity class . after rule engine execution,  i am getting only null value in output.

**Pojo Struture :**

```
Opportunity.Java :
    private java.lang.Boolean result;
    private java.lang.String ip;
    private java.util.List<com.sample2.sampledemo2.OpportunityProduct> productlist;

OpportunityProduct.Java
    private java.lang.String name;
```

**Input:**

```
{
   "commands":[
      {
         "insert":{
            "out-identifier":"com.sample2.sampledemo2.Opportunity",
            "return-object":true,
            "object":{
               "com.sample2.sampledemo2.Opportunity":{
                  "productlist":[
                     {
                        "name":"abc"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "fire-all-rules":""
      }
   ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
   "type":"SUCCESS",
   "msg":"Container abcdef successfully called.",
   "result":{
      "execution-results":{
         "results":[
            {
               "key":"",
               "value":0
            },
            {
               "key":"com.sample2.sampledemo2.Opportunity",
               "value":{
                  "com..sample2.sampledemo2.Opportunity":{
                     "result":null,
                     "ip":null,
                     "productlist":[
                        {
                           "name":"abc"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "facts":[
            {
               "key":"com.sample2.sampledemo2.Opportunity",
               "value":{
                  "org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle":{
                     "external-form":"0:2:1366747666:1366747666:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.sample2.sampledemo2.Opportunity"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Decision Table :**

```
NAME                  CONDITION                               ACTION

           o:Opportunity(pd: productlist)
             OpportunityProduct
      (name == $param , this memberOf pd)      o.setIp($param);

Origination  "abc"                                  "IPP"
```

**Drl :**

```
rule "Origination"
    when
        o:Opportunity(pd: productlist)
        (OpportunityProduct(name == "abc" , this memberOf pd))
    then
        o.setIp("IPP");
end
```

I could not able to identify whether my input is wrong or  condition in decision table is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your input, you are sending a `Opportunity` object to be inserted, but you are never inserting a `OpportunityProduct` fact. Your rule needs both facts in order to fire.

Remember that, in Drools, you can only reason about facts that have been inserted into your session and that **nested objects inside a fact are not facts** themselves.

If you don't plan to insert `OpportunityProduct` as independent facts, one thing you can do is to use the `from` conditional element to reason about data that is not a fact:

```
rule "Origination"
    when
        o:Opportunity(pd: productlist)
        OpportunityProduct(name == "abc") from pd
    then
        o.setIp("IPP");
end
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that by default the kie-server rest interface works like this :

1) On the client side A related to B (A.b=b)

2) You insert A and then B

3) on server-side, there is going to be for each insert command :

3.1) an A object (inserted into the kie-session) related to a B1 instance (that is not inserted)

3.2) another B2 instance (exact copy content of B1 but not related to A)

Here two solutions :

1) Live with that and use from

2) make your own kie-server extension and it is what I do [on my open source project to make life  easier with drools](https://github.com/pymma/pymma-kie-platform/tree/master/drools-framework-base-tools-parent/drools-framework-kie-server-parent/drools-framework-kie-server-rest-drools) . All my customer are using this kind of kie-server woth inserting by reflection all java objects connected to a top object (called request most of the time)

regards